# Cannot change npm version in WebStorm

Tags: npm, webstorm

I have just installed the latest Node.js - `v15.9.0 (includes npm 7.5.3)` and then updated my IDE (WebStorm) settings to serve this latest Node.js. I then restarted my IDE and now in the terminal window within it (my terminal points to Git Bash) I can see that `node -v` has changed to 15.9.0, which is correct, but npm version is still 6.9.0. And I don't know how to change it.

Because npm version is different, I get "npm WARN npm does not support Node.js v15.9.0" error in the IDE and cannot do anything with npm as it is simply not working.

In Settings, npm path is the same as Node.js path:
`C:\Program Files\node.js-15.9.0\node.exe` and `C:\Program Files\node.js-15.9.0\node_modules\npm`.

If I start Git Bash outside IDE, `npm -v` is 7.5.3, which is correct. I simply have no clue how this have happened. I have also set my user environment variables. Please help me to fix npm version within WebStorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `which npm` command in Git Bash in Webstorm (if in CMD, command is `where npm`) and it revealed a path to the npm module within my project: `project-name/node_modules/.bin/npm`
I removed node_modules folder and then restarted the IDE, and now the path is correct, it's version 7.5.3.